# How many CICERO cubesats are in space now? What are their IDs?

Tags: identify-this-object, cicero-constellation

Trying to better understand the situation discussed in [CICERO orbit design and optimization for GPS occultations?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31949/12102) I decided to look these satellites up, but got stuck right away.

Gunter's space page for [CICERO](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/cicero.htm) has CICERO-4 and 5 blank, and and the COSPAR ID assignments for  CICERO-1, 2, and 3 with question marks. CICERO-10 is reported to be on Rocket Labs' “It’s Business Time” launch in agreement with that page.

Is there a definitive source somewhere that gives the name and COSPAR/SatCat (International Designator/NORAD Catalog Number) of each one that is currently in space?

```
spacecraft   Gunter's        Celestrak    
 name        SpacePage       SATCAT
----------   ------------    ---------
CICERO-1     2017-042C ?
CICERO-2     2017-042M ?
CICERO-3     2017-042AA ?
CICERO-4      -
CICERO-5      -
CICERO-6     2017-036AE      2017-036AE 42793
CICERO-7     2018-004AJ      2018-004AJ 43143
CICERO-8      -
CICERO-9      -
CICERO-10    2018-088
CICERO-11    
CICERO-12
```

Celestrak's SATCAT lists `42827`, `42836`, and `42849` for the COSPAR IDs' that Gunter's Space Page theorizes for CICERO-1, 2, and 3, but even today they are only called `OBJECT-C`, `OBJECT-M`, and  `OBJECT-AA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gunther's list seems to be accurate. As it mentioned there, 3 were launched on a single launch, and were never heard from again. It is too difficult to figure out which of the 30+ objects was which, Gunther seems to have the best guesses for the values. The other 3 are all accepted by Space Track, as they worked and could be positively identified.

CICERO 10 is 2018-088a

Comment: It is the A payload, edited to include that.

Answer (score 3):

CICERO spacecraft are assigned sequential numbers by the system when launches are booked.  The numbers are not re-used even if a launch is canceled.  Six have been launched to date, two are now operating, known internally as OP1-A and OP1-B.

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to Space! Can you add a supporting source or link for this information, so that I and future readers will know what it is that makes you believe this to be true? Also, have a look at the table in my post; can you address the rest of the question: *What are their IDs?*